# Eclipse C compilation not working

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, compilation

I downloaded Eclipse C/C++ for windows. Unfortunately i compile and start this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

First all i got this: symbol stdio.h stdlib.h and exit_succes  can not be resolved.
After i tried to build it i cant even run it. WHen i run it straight i got this 4 errors:

```
> -Program "g++" not found in PATH(Scanner)
> -Program "gcc" not found in PATH(Scanner)
> -Program "make" not found in PATH(Problem)
> -Symbol 'EXIT_SUCCES'could not be resolved (Semantic Error)
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You have to install a c compiler, like gcc, cygwin, or mingw

Comment: You even can use command line Microsoft C++ compiler, but this requires additional setup http://codewriterstips.blogspot.ru/2012/05/using-microsoft-c-compiler-with-eclipse.html

Comment: You could download the Code::Blocks IDE and a compiler for Windows in one bundle at their site.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is not a compiler, and apparently you don't have the compilers eclipse is expecting installed, so it complains. I think the first choice for a compiler on windows is gcc from [minGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

The last error simply means that EXIT_SUCCES is not defined. I think you mean EXIT_SUCCESS, but that is just a guess.